# How can I collapse a ContentControl that's showing the default template?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Let's say I have a ContentControl with a ContentTemplateSelector. If the Content doesn't map to a template in the DataTemplateSelector, it seems that the ContentControl defaults to displaying the Content's type as a string in a TextBlock. I want to collapse the ContentControl in this default case. Is that possible?

Comment: _"If the Content doesn't map to a template in the DataTemplateSelector..."_ -- I don't understand. Assuming you wrote the `DataTemplateSelector`, why aren't you just returning a collapsed template in the "didn't match something I wanted" case? You have complete control over the template at that point...why abandon that control only to then present yourself (and us!) with a question about how to get control over the situation back?

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Great suggestion. In my mind, I got stuck on setting Visibility on the ContentControl itself.

Comment: In any case, without a proper [mcve] showing what the trouble is, along with an explanation of how you've tried to solve that trouble and what _specifically_ you need help with, this question has too many possible answers to be suitable for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the Content doesn't map to a template in the DataTemplateSelector

This shouldn't happen.
Does your `ContentTemplateSelector` return null in some cases?
Returning null is effectively the same as returning `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>`.
Instead of null, return an empty template

```
   private statiс readonly DataTemplate Empty = new DataTemplate();

    ------------
   {
       -----------
       return Empty;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The responsibility of a `ContentTemplateSelector` is to select a template based on the `Content`.

If you want to hide the entire `ControlControl`, you could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to the same property that you use to select a template in the `ContentTemplateSelector`:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProperty}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Note that the logic that decides whether to hide the control doesn't belong to the selector.